# Is this a safe way to use goto?

Tags: c#, loops, goto

```
foreach (var thing in things)
{
    tryagain:
    string thing.var1 = ThisCanReturnNullSometimes();
    if (thing.var1 == null)
    {
        goto tryagain;
    }
}
```

I know ideally you don't want a method that can "fail" but I'm working with the youtube data API and for some reason some calls just.. don't follow through.

It seems like a short and sweet way to reattempt the iteration, but i've never used a goto before and I've only heard people say don't use it.

Comment: why not a while loop?  it better conveys intent... while this is null, get another

Comment: it is "safe", but that doesn't mean it's a good idea. you want to minimize "wtfs per minute" of reading your code, and goto is an unnecessary wtf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most programs can be expressed without goto. In this particular case, a loop is a far more readable construct, because it says pretty much what you want it to say:

```
string x;
do {
    x=CanReturnNullSometimes();
} while (x==null);
```

One nice thing about this loop is that the readers always know its post-condition: the only way this loop can terminate is that x becomes non-null. You can also add safety check to ensure that you are not calling the method too many times.

Comment: The interesting question if there are more people who know of existence of `do-while` loop or `goto` :)

Comment: This is better than my method since you don't have to give the method twice.

Comment: @KeithNicholas can you define "safe" (as OP did not)? In my opinion all `goto` in C# are "safe" (or code will not compile). You can't have valid C# code that compiles to unverifiable IL for example...

Comment: @KeithNicholas goto is safe in your situation. However, it does not mean that one should use it for simple looping, because readability suffers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  not my situation :)

Comment: I really like this, I don't know why I jumped to goto before thinking about this. Brain fart. Thanks!

Comment: @KeithNicholas I don't think OP used word "safe" in true meaning... Probably more like "should I use goto to retry user input" similar how "the best way" used for "just give me the code" in other SO posts.

Answer (score 0):

Your goto is safe, but is generally not used.  Essentially you have written an implementation of a while loop.

But your code does have an interesting trait, your variable can be scoped and  assigned and still be available after the loop... which can be concisely done like :-

```
tryagain: var s = ThisCanReturnNullSometimes();
if (s == null) goto tryagain;
```

however, while that is interesting.... I'd stick with a while loop or helper method if you'd like it more concise

Of course, it also has the additional problem of being an infinite loop in the case of null being returned all the time.

Answer (score -1):

You would probably be better off using something like a `while` loop to monitor the status of your method and keep trying it. You could add a maximum iteration check to make sure it doesn't just loop forever.

```
string thing.var1 = ThisCanReturnNullSometimes();
int iteration = 0;
while (thing.var1 == null && iteration < 5)
{    
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // sleep for a bit to give the remove service time to "work"
    thing.var1 = ThisCanReturnNullSometimes();
    iteration++;
}
```

This will sleep for 5 seconds then try the method again and repeat up to 5 times before continuing on.

Of course, the best way would be to work out why your method fails, if it's a common problem or something that can be fixed.